# Compile dependencies dynamically based on spring.profiles.active

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Can someone please guide me where to start this task?

I'd simply have to exclude `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` when deploying to jboss.

I imagine it will look something like:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"){
        if(getProperty "spring.profiles.active" == "qat")
            exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

With the sample above, I get an error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'spring.profiles.active' for DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='org.springframework.boot', name='spring-boot-starter-web', version='null', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.
```

Maybe I could create a custom task to set `spring.profiles.active` on the task. HELP!

Comment: Where is defined `spring.profiles.active`?

Comment: @ToYonos, Its in src_server/main/resources/application.yml.

Comment: so `getProperty "spring.profiles.active"` is not really a thing ? It's not a method which reads `application.yml` ?

Comment: I get an error with the sample code above. I've edited the question to include the error message.

Comment: Are you creating a WAR file? Note that Gradle knows nothing about the _application.yml_ file. Also, are you sure that's where `spring.profiles.active` is supposed to be defined? From what I remember, _application.yml_ allows you to specify different values based on the value of `spring.profiles.active`.

Comment: Yes. It's for a war file. I'm very new to spring-boot and gradle. I've posted my answer to my question. Thanks for your help anyways @PeterLedbrook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter Ledbrook mentioned, gradle does not have access to spring-boot's application.yml at compile time. And the `dependencies` run very early in gradle's lifecycle that a task is never called before `dependencies` are resolved.

Even trying *dependency resolution strategy* was futile.

So I just had to do:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        if(System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active") == "qat"){
          exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
        }
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    if(System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active") == "qat"){
        providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
    }
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Then I'll type `gradle build -Dspring-profiles-active=qat` when deploying to jboss. and `gradle bootRun -Dspring-profiles-active=dev` when I have to run locally.